# Detecting when the Control key has been released

Tags: c, linux, gtk, keyboard-events

I'm trying to detect when the Control key has been released with this code:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <gtk/gtk.h>

int main (int argc, char* argv[])
{
    const unsigned int pause_microseconds = 100 * 1000;

    gtk_init(&argc, &argv);

    GdkModifierType mask;
    while (1) {
        if(gdk_window_get_pointer(NULL, NULL, NULL, &mask) == NULL){
            puts("gdk_window_get_pointer failed");
            return EXIT_FAILURE;
        }

        unsigned control_has_been_released = (mask & GDK_CONTROL_MASK) != GDK_CONTROL_MASK;
        if (control_has_been_released) {
            puts("OK");
            return EXIT_SUCCESS;
        }

        if(usleep(pause_microseconds) != 0){
            puts("usleep failed");
            return EXIT_FAILURE;
        }
    }
}
```

But I get this output:

```
 gdk_window_get_pointer failed
```

Code compiled with:

```
 gcc -Wall -g ctrl.c -o ctrl `pkg-config --cflags gtk+-2.0` `pkg-config --libs gtk+-2.0`
```

I have tried running the code as root, but the result is the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`gdk_window_get_pointer()`](https://developer.gnome.org/gdk2/stable/gdk2-Windows.html#gdk-window-get-pointer) cannot be called with a `NULL` first argument; i.e. you need to specify a window.

On top of that, in order to be able to see the changes, you probably need to run the event loop, see [Getting keyboard modifiers state using Gnome libs (GDK) fetches initial state only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31826035/getting-keyboard-modifiers-state-using-gnome-libs-gdk-fetches-initial-state-on).